# Assign values to multicolumn dataframe using another dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am trying to assign values to a multicolumn dataframe that are stored in another normal dataframe. The 2 dataframes share the same index, however when attempting to assign the values for all columns of the normal dataframe to a slice of the multicolumn dataframe `Nan` values appear.

### MWE

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        ("old", "mean"): {"high": 0.0, "med": 0.0, "low": 0.0},
        ("old", "std"): {"high": 0.0, "med": 0.0, "low": 0.0},
        ("new", "mean"): {"high": 0.0, "med": 0.0, "low": 0.0},
        ("new", "std"): {"high": 0.0, "med": 0.0, "low": 0.0},
    }
)

temp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        "old": {
            "high": 2.6798302797288174,
            "med": 10.546654056177656,
            "low": 16.46382603916123,
        },
        "new": {
            "high": 15.91881231611413,
            "med": 16.671967271277495,
            "low": 26.17872356316402,
        },
    }
)

df.loc[:, (slice(None), "mean")] = temp
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      old       new     
     mean  std mean  std
high  NaN  0.0  NaN  0.0
med   NaN  0.0  NaN  0.0
low   NaN  0.0  NaN  0.0
```

Is this expected behaviour or am I doing something horrible that I am not supposed?

Comment: Pandas fully aligns across the axes. If you look at your slice: `df.loc[:, (slice(None), "mean")]` you still have a MultiIndex on the columns but `temp` does not, so because nothing aligns everything gets `NaN`d. I.e. just make `temp` have a MultiIndex too: `temp.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([temp.columns, ['mean']])`

Comment: @ALollz thanks I see, is there an easy way to resolve this other than looping through each column of `temp` and assigning it to the corresponding col of `df`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `MultiIndex` in `temp` for align data and then you can set new values by [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
temp.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([temp.columns, ['mean']])
print (temp)
            old        new
           mean       mean
high   2.679830  15.918812
med   10.546654  16.671967
low   16.463826  26.178724

df.update(temp)
print(df)
            old             new     
           mean  std       mean  std
high   2.679830  0.0  15.918812  0.0
med   10.546654  0.0  16.671967  0.0
low   16.463826  0.0  26.178724  0.0
```